# unable to view Word or pdf file in android using webview_flutter pakage

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am attempting to display a Word document in an Android app using the webview_flutter package. However, I'm encountering an issue where the screen remains blank, and the document is not displayed. Strangely, this problem only occurs on Android, while it works correctly on iOS. I have already added internet permissions to the AndroidManifest.xml file. My minimum SDK version is set to 21.
Here is my code,

```
 Container(
        
          constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: BaseDimen.containerFull),

          child: WebViewWidget(
            controller: WebViewController()
              ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
              ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
              ..setNavigationDelegate(
                NavigationDelegate(
                  onProgress: (int progress) {
                    showProgress
                        ? const Center(
                            child: SizedBox(
                              height: 200,
                              width: 200,
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                color: BaseColor.primaryLight,
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        : Stack();
                  },
                  onPageStarted: (String url) {},
                  onPageFinished: (String url) {},
                  onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {},
                  onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
                    if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/')) {
                      return NavigationDecision.prevent;
                    }
                    return NavigationDecision.navigate;
                  },
                ),
              )
              ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(url)),
          ),
        ),
```

Kindy resolve it

Comment: Did you try the InAppWebView package? In my view, It's more convenient.

Comment: No i have not as it required to do it with webview_flutter

Comment: A normal Android WebView cannot display pdf and word files. Just try a html file to see if the code is ok.

Comment: yes html file is working